# Why am I getting "bind source path does not exist" from Docker on Windows in Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file where I'm mounting a volume with `bind` like so:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  backend:
    image: gitlab:5000/foo/bar/backend:${CI_COMMIT_SHA}
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ../backend
        target: /var/www/html
      - type: bind
        source: ../backend
        target: /var/envs
    environment:
      SRV_ENV: 'development'
```

In the Windows Subsystem for Linux (Ubuntu) bash shell I `cd` to `/home/urig/src/foo/bar/deploy`.

When I then run :

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml down
```

I get the following error:

```
starting server...
Creating network "deploy_default" with the default driver
Creating deploy_backend_1    ... error
ERROR: for deploy_backend_1  Cannot create container for service backend: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /home/urig/src/foo/bar/backend

ERROR: for backend  Cannot create container for service backend: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /home/urig/src/foo/bar/backend
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
ERROR: No container found for backend_1
```

**Why can't WSL find the source folder and how can I fix this?**

I am using Docker Desktop (for Windows) CE v2.0.0.2. Docker Engine v18.09.1, docker-compose v1.23.2

Comment: See here: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2151

Comment: @henry thanks. Just tried @jamesyale's suggestion there and got pretty much the same error: `bind source path does not exist: /mnt/c/Users/urig/src/foo/bar/backend`

Comment: @andolsizied thanks. I've tried an absolute path but it didn't work. The path shown in the error message is derived correctly from the relative path in the `.yml` file. Docker just thinks it's empty.

Comment: It seems you try to mount a directory within your WSL and not from Windows C drive. I don't think this will work at all.

Comment: @henry I copied the directory over to the Windows file system too - still does not work.

Comment: after copying to windows file system provide windows file convention like `c:\users\`

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this issue and took me a few tries...

- Windows 10 version 18.03   17134.1006
- Docker version 18.09.7, build 2d0083d
- docker-compose version 1.24.1, build 4667896b

I was running `docker-compose up --build` when I get the above error. One of my bindings where against `/home/c/folder` and this is the point that was having issues when running:

```
Creating sytraining11_sytraining11-codevalidation_1 ... done
compose.parallel.parallel_execute_iter: Finished processing: ServiceName(project='sytraining11', service='sytraining11-codevalidation', number=1)
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.parallel_execute_iter: Finished processing: <Service: sytraining11-codevalidation>
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()

ERROR: for sytraining11-dev  Cannot create container for service sytraining11-dev: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /home/c/folder
ERROR: compose.cli.main.main: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

The solution was this: I changed that mount point from `/home/c/folder` to `/mnt/f/folder` and everything started working again.

**NOTE**: When I setup WSL+docker, `docker-compose` worked fine for about two days. However, I restarted the Docker machine in Windows and the error showed up.

I will like to add this guide as a reference:

- [Docker for Windows](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly)
- [Try to run in WSL](https://github.com/cdr/sail/issues/210#issuecomment-499765224)

I have to admit these links might have helped in a way but I cannot confirm if they had any effect at the end. Despite of my vague answer, I would like to share it  as this could provide some details during this type of troubleshooting process.

***** Edit:

Additional resource that summarizes this type of troubleshooting [here](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/docker_installation/)